# fields does not exist error (working with odoo 12)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-12

i was trying to install a module but each time there is an error like this :
Erreur:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1126, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 351, in _check_xml
    self.postprocess_and_fields(view.model, view_doc, view.id)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 1131, in postprocess_and_fields
    self.raise_view_error(message, view_id)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 568, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Le champ `nbre_ch` n'existe pas

Contexte de l'erreur :
Vue `Product`
[view_id: 1029, xml_id: n/a, model: product.template, parent_id: 496]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 663, in _tag_record
    record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3888, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 129, in _load_records_create
    records = super(View, self)._load_records_create(values)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3802, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-32>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 428, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3619, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1141, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 275, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 41, in write
    return super(View, self).write(vals)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 445, in write
    res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3344, in write
    self._write(store_vals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3480, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1130, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ("Erreur lors de la validation de la contrainte\n\nLe champ `nbre_ch` n'existe pas\n\nContexte de l'erreur :\nVue `Product`\n[view_id: 1029, xml_id: n/a, model: product.template, parent_id: 496]", None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 98, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 445, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 802, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 865, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 764, in parse
    exc_info[2]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 663, in _tag_record
    record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3888, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 129, in _load_records_create
    records = super(View, self)._load_records_create(values)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3802, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-32>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 428, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3619, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1141, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 275, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 41, in write
    return super(View, self).write(vals)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 445, in write
    res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3344, in write
    self._write(store_vals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3480, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1130, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Erreur lors de la validation de la contrainte

Le champ `nbre_ch` n'existe pas

Contexte de l'erreur :
Vue `Product`
[view_id: 1029, xml_id: n/a, model: product.template, parent_id: 496]
None" while parsing file:/c:/program%20files%20(x86)/odoo%2012.0/server/odoo/addons/gestionimmo/views/gesimmo_views.xml:7, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_form_gesimmo">
      <field name="name">Product</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <data><!--<xpath expr="//field[@name='default_code']" position="after">
              <group>
                <field name="prop" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="ref" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="surface" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="immo_cat" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="immo_titre" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="immo_date" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/><br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <field name="img_one" widget="image" style="width:400%%"/>
                  <field name="refimmo"/>
              </group>
          </xpath>-->
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='standard_price']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='barcode']" position="attributes" nolabel="true">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='categ_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='type']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='default_code']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//label[@for='standard_price']" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='taxes_id']" position="after">
              <group>
                <field name="nbre_ch" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <field name="pr" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                   <field name="rue" placeholder="Rue" style="width:300%%"/>
                <field name="gouv" placeholder="Gouvernorat" style="width:300%%"/>
                <field name="ville" placeholder="Ville" style="width:300%%"/>
                <field name="codepostal" placeholder="Code postal" style="width:300%%"/>
                <field name="pays" placeholder="Pays" style="width:300%%" readonly="1"/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <field name="img_two" widget="image" style="width:400%%"/>
              </group>
          </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='taxes_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='list_price']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <label for="name" position="replace">
                    <label for="name" string="Nom du bien immobilier"/>
                </label>
          <!--<label for="sale_ok" position="replace">
                    <label for="sale_ok"  string="A Vendre"/>
                </label>-->
          <!--<label for="purchase_ok" position="replace">
                    <label for="purchase_ok"  string="A Louer"/>
                </label>-->
          <xpath expr="//page[@name='variants']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//page[@name='sales']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//page[@name='purchase']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//page[@name='inventory']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>

          <xpath expr="//field[@name='pays']" position="before">
    <button name="open_map" type="object" icon="/GestionIMMO/static/src/img/google_maps.png"/>
          </xpath>
         <!--<button name="action_update_quantity_on_hand" position = "attributes" >
        <attribute name = "invisible">1</attribute>
    </button>-->
          <xpath expr="//button[@name='toggle_active']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_view_sales']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_view_po']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <!--<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_open_quants']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>-->
          <!--<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_view_stock_move_lines']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>-->
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_ok']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='purchase_ok']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
          <label for="sale_ok" position="replace">
                    <label for="sale_ok" invisible="1"/>
                </label>
           <label for="purchase_ok" position="replace">
                    <label for="purchase_ok" invisible="1"/>
                </label>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">

               <!--<field name="a_louer" invisible="1"/>-->
               <!--<field name="type_b" widget="radio" class="oe_edit_only" options="{'horizontal': true}"/>-->
               <!--<field name="choix_type" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'color_field': 'color', 'no_create_edit': True}" placeholder="Tags..." default="name"/>-->

            </xpath>
          <!--<xpath expr="//field[@name='immo_date']" position="after">
                  <field name="description_bien" placeholder="Description..." style="width:300%%"/>
          </xpath>-->

          <!--<xpath expr="//button[@name='356']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>-->

           <!--<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_view_orderpoints']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>-->
          <!--<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_open_product_lot']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>-->
      </data></field>
    </record>
```

but the field does exist in .py file and in the xml view , i checked my init.py and everything is fine , i tried to comment the field in the xml and the .py file and run it again and it is the same error with another field ..  Please help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added dependency of `product` module in your manifest file. Or something is missing on init file level.

Comment: yes i already mentioned  it in the manifest file still the same error =(