# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib' (ODOO 12)

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

i have this error running odoo-log, i installed odoo 12 correctly , postgresql as well.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\python.exe" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Odoo 12.0/server/odoo-bin"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Odoo 12.0/server/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from . import service
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import wsgi_server
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 25, in <module>
    import werkzeug.contrib.fixers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is the configuration :
[image]
[image]
HELP PLEASE , i tried almost everything but no result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems some issue with the new/current version 1.0.0 of the Werkzeug installation

Try these commands:

```
pip3 uninstall Werkzeug  # will uninstall earlier version
pip3 install Werkzeug==0.11.15  # check the requirements.txt and installed that version
```

Otherwise, you can use [cachelib](https://github.com/pallets/cachelib) as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: can you please help me with this issue please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787482/fields-does-not-exist-error-working-with-odoo-12/61789302#61789302